# Overriding the default controller method using restfull Yii extension

Tags: php, yii

I am building on an application in which i need to built the API's and then i found this extenison : **Link below ->**

https://github.com/evan108108/RESTFullYii

But i was wondering that how to override the existing methods present in the controller.

For eg. 
I have my actionView method as follows:

```
public function actionView($id) {
    $this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

And this outputs me the all the fields from the database. But the thing i want is that i should write some logic and the output should be generated according to my logic.

Please help me. I am stuck???

Comment: So, why don't you just write some logic in the function, what is holding you back?